# Exporting html table to excel/pdf

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

JSP file

```
        <div class="row" ng-controller="dataExportCtrl">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4 class="blue ">Search Result</h4>
              <div id="tableToExport" class="table-responsive mt10">
                <table class="table table-hover " id="table-grid">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Client</th>
                      <th>Production vs Workplace</th>
                      <th>Rule type</th>
                      <th>SynID and description</th>
                      <th>Message</th>
                      <th>Notes</th>
                      <th>Release date</th>
                      <th>Checked-out by</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="ruleData in ctrl.ruleDataList">
                        <td>{{ruleData[7]}}</td>
                        <td>Suspendisse ut scelerisque<br>Aeneann pulvinar lectus.<br>pulvinar lectus.</td>
                        <td>{{ruleData[24]}}</td>
                        <td>{{ruleData[5]}} <br> {{ruleData[2]}}</td>
                        <td>{{ruleData[3]}}</td>
                        <td>{{ruleData[4]}}</td>
                        <td>20 Oct 22:30</td>
                        <td>Editor name01<br>20 Oct 22:30</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                                 <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                  <li ng-click="editRule(ruleData)"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View / Edit</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Check out</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Undo check-out</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Check in</a></li>
                                  <li ng-click="deleteSearchResult($index,ruleData[23])"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 mt20 text-right">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" ng-click="exportToExcel('#tableToExport')"> Export 
                   <span class="btn-label"><i class="icon-append fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></span></button>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Js File

```
app.factory('Excel',function($window){
    var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
        format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
    return {
        tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
            var table=$(tableId),
                ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
})
.controller('dataExportCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout,$scope){
  $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
        var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'Searched Rule Data');
        $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
    }
});
```

Now the thing is that everything is working fine, i am able to export table contents in excel,but they are not ordered plus it includes button of popup(view,edit & all). I don't want them.Excel file snapshot link has been attached
Excel Snapshot:http://tinypic.com/r/14vgv2d/9

And this is how UI look when we press edit button on it.
http://tinypic.com/r/hwajcg/9.
Now what i want is simply extract table without edit buttons contents into excel or pdf format on click of export button.

Comment: Instead of going from scratch, why not use an existing plug-in like this one https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin ?

Comment: i have never used a plugin from git. i don't know how to use it plus using a plugin is also not in team requirement. But can u explain me how to use this plugin from scratch?

Comment: Well the doc is fairly well documented. Just go and read it :). Basicaly, all you have to do is download the files, put them on your project js folder, reference it on your code and follow the instructions. Give it a try! There are even all made samples!

Comment: Okay i will give it a try. Can u suggest something in above code so that i can exclude buttons from my excel

Comment: @PierreBurton where to use options(default settings)?

Comment: The options are to be used as arguments of the tableExport method. e.g. $('#tableID').tableExport({type:'excel'}); As you can see, the argument of the function is an object (which can contain up to all the values mentionned in the doc) here specifying the type "excel"., you can add more like this $('#tableID').tableExport({type:'excel', fileName: 'myFileName'});

Comment: i have successfully used the plugin but problem i'm now facing is that autotable:'linebreak ' was not working for that i used columnWidth: 'wrap' & columnStyles: {  columnName: {columnWidth: 'auto'}} which worked as an alternate for it. But now what this actually does is,it make column spaces shifted to right due to which my last column's text is only partially visible. Link for above problem image is:http://tinypic.com/r/2ur1eoh/9

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTables.

**HTML**

```
<table id="tbl" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Making table more interactive:

- Pagination
- Horizontal scroll
- Ordering (ASC or DESC)
- Rows display length
- Output PDF orientation

**Updated JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').DataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [[3,5, 10, 25, -1], [3, 5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 3,
        "order": [],
        "scrollX": true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
        ],
        buttons: [
            'pageLength',
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'LEGAL', 
            },
            'copy', 'excel' 
        
        ]
    } );
    
} );
```

Comment: You could add a link to the official site (the documentation can be useful) : https://datatables.net/